# Filter (no display) layers in GeoExt.LegendPanel using LIKE operator

Tags: filter, panel, openlayers, legend, geoext

This works to avoid Basemap layers such as Google Maps and overlays such as WMS to appear in the GeoExt Legend Panel:

```
var legendPanel = new GeoExt.LegendPanel({
    border: false,
    filter: function(record){
        if(!(record.getLayer().isBaseLayer) && (record.getLayer() instanceof OpenLayers.Layer.WMS)){
        return true;
        }
    } });
```

The problem is that I need to filter (ie. no display) layers with names having "beam" in their names, I tried with no success this:

```
return record.getLayer().displayInLayerSwitcher == false && record.getLayer().name == '%beam%';
return record.getLayer().displayInLayerSwitcher == false &&
record.get("layer").name.indexOf("%beam%") == -1;
return record.get("layer").name.indexOf("%beam%") == -1;
```

Any hints are welcomed,

Comment: Why did you surround the keyword with `%` in the first place?

Comment: @kryger thanks for the idea, just got the solution, please check igor's answer below.

Comment: sure it's crosposted, I'm looking for a solution, what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the "%". Use

```
return record.getLayer().name.indexOf("beam") == -1;
```

instead of

```
return record.getLayer().name.indexOf("%beam%") == -1;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but using your suggestion gives `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null`. Afaik, this means that `name` (thus `indexOf`) are null or empty. That can be true because no layers have been uploaded yet, but the idea is to apply this filter once layers are uploaded. Any additional idea?

Comment: Hard to say what the problem is without seeing the full code. See the working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/igor23/a1nkt9vk/ . In this example, legend panel doesn't show legend image for layer named "beam". Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks!! I found the solution!